# empty page after executing statement

Tags: php, mysql

I write a program that output the animal name from the database.However I'm having a problem that my program can not execute the case when it doesn't find the right value (values that are not in the database)

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='root';
$dbname='pet';
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) or die("can not connect to server");

if(@$_GET['data']=='yes')
{
    $animalName=trim($_POST['animal']);
    $query="SELECT name FROM display WHERE name='$animalName'";
    $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("can not execute query");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        extract($row);
        if(!$name==$animalName)
        {
            echo "not found";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Hello $name. Have a nice day.";
        }
    }

}
else
{
        echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?data=yes' method='POST'>
            <h4>type an animal name in the box below and press enter</h4>
            <p><input type='text' name='animal' maxlength='20'></p>
            <p><input type='submit' value='submit'></p>
            </form>";
}
?>
```

When i type an animal that doesn't exist in the database my code can't execute this block (it  turn to an empty page)

```
if(!$name==$animalName)
            {
                echo "not found";
            }
```

is there any solution.

Comment: `if(!$name==$animalName)` doesn't do what you think it does.  It should be `if($name!==$animalName)`.  P.S. Don't do `extract($row)`, it's dangerous, just do `if($row['name']!==$animalName)`.

Comment: If you are getting a blank page, that means you are getting a PHP error.  Try adding `ini_set('display_errors ', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of you page.

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). And use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when outputting to HTML to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29). And you can't be sure that if `$_GET['data']` contains `yes`, that other variables are present.

Comment: You have another bug. The mysql_fetch_assoc() will return zero rows if the animal is not in the database. In this case, the while loop will never execute and you will not output anything to a web page.

Comment: Now change your password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  `mysqli_num_rows()` before while loop

```
<?php
$host     = 'localhost';
$user     = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$dbname   = 'pet';
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname) or die("can not connect to server");

if (@$_GET['data'] == 'yes') {
    $animalName = trim($_POST['animal']);
    $query      = "SELECT name FROM display WHERE name='$animalName'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die("can not execute query");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            extract($row);
            if (!$name == $animalName) {
                echo "not found";
            } else {
                echo "Hello $name. Have a nice day.";
            }
        }
    } else
        echo "data not found";

} else {
    echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?data=yes' method='POST'>
                    <h4>type an animal name in the box below and press enter</h4>
                    <p><input type='text' name='animal' maxlength='20'></p>
                    <p><input type='submit' value='submit'></p>
                    </form>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't get any rows in the result set from the database, the code inside the while loop will never execute.

What you likely need to do is check the number of rows in the result set before trying to enter the while loop.  If you have 0 rows, just issue the message and do not try to "fetch" any results from the database in the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($name != $animalName) {
```

Your query is also vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a check for the mysql_query() returning no rows when the SELECT fails due to no animal in the db. Add the following after your $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) statement:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo "not found";
}
```